# How to code an external login for Woltlab Burning Board 3?

Tags: php, forum

I am looking for a way to make my own login formular in PHP to log in with my extisting Wbb3 account. The login will be on the same server, so i've got access to the database and the salts, but I'm missing the way how to encrypt the password.

Any tutorials?

Comment: If this is OpenSource Software, check their sourcecode to see how they authenticate users.

Comment: It's not open source (at least not completely - large parts of the framework used are LGPL'd but parts of the forums are commercial) but the full sourcecode is visible for everyone who bought the software. So checking the code is indeed a possibility - and for this part checking the LGPL'd code is even enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salting in WBB3 is like

```
$pw = sha1 (salt . sha1 (salt. sha1(password_from_field)));
```

Look in /lib/util/StringUtil.class.php